# Strange effect header fixed in safari iOS

Tags: ios, css, safari, fixed

I have this code for a header fixed. When the scroll bar down, I add the class .headerFixed to the id #navHeader.

But I have a problem, in Chrome browser it works perfectly but in Safari iOS appears a strange effect (animate to left and right when appears the fixed header)

Any idea ?

Thanks

```
#navHeader {
    height: 96px;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    z-index: 3;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

.headerFixed{
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 9 !important;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have a similar issue, here is a link to a video that shows the problem in action.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9247710/2016-08-17%2012.54.16.mp4

The homepage opens with a fixed header. As you scroll down the page, things are fine. The Safari App bar shrinks when the page is first touched, and the nav adheres to the top of the viewport just fine. BUT, when you hit the menu icon to open the left drawer the whole page sort of magically glides up and under the Safari app bar.

Both the header and the drawer have `position: fixed` applied to them. The `<body>` uses `position: relative; overflow-y:scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`. Might be worth noting that I am doing the animation/transition on the left drawer and page wrapper with `translate3d()`.

Comment: Deploying a fix where when the `.js-navigation-open__active` class is present on the `<html>` element, we change the height to `height: 100vh` and force `overflow: hidden`. Seems to do the trick, confirming shortly

Comment: As far as I can tell so far, it works. Something about using `height: 100%` for iOS was incorrectly calculating the height of the elements. The viewport height unit correctly calculates height. 

I hope this helps you or someone else.